# ssl mixed content errors in browser

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mixed-content

I have recently installed a flexible ssl on a Wordpress website using CloudFlare. I have read around the issues others have had. I have installed various plugins to remedy the problem. I have tested the url on an ssl checker which says it is OK. When the page first loads I have the green lock - it subsequently goes Amber with an exclamation (on Firefox) or just the 'i' on Chrome.

Chrome console says: 
`Mixed Content: The page at https://example.com/ was loaded over HTTPS, but     requested an insecure image http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/logo1.png. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`

In Chrome console it shows that there are some images which load are loading with http - but if you look at the actual image in the WP library it has https in front, including the one above. If I look at images on the front page with say Firefox developer all image paths are preceded https://. If I check the logo image guid in the WP DB which is throwing the error on the front page then it is https://. I have purged the Couldflare cache. I have cleared all browser cache.

So what's the problem?

Comment: If you copy one of the image URLs—for example,`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/logo1.png`—into your browser address bar and try to view it, does the browser actually load it over https? Or does it instead get redirected to `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/logo1.png` (non-https)?

Comment: Thanks. I finally managed it. I found a hard link to the logo in the CSS file which I changed. Checking the theme files for hard links seems the way to go. Cleared the whole cache and it now works. Thanks anyway.